# Discord.js Guild Member Count in Status will not be updated if someone leaves

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a status that counts the server members. As soon as someone comes in, the bot updates. But if someone leaves, no update happens.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    // Auto Change Status

    function picksStatus() {
        let status = [`mit ${client.users.cache.filter(u => !u.bot).size} User`, `${prefix}help für Hilfe`];

        let statusRotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * status.length);

        client.user.setActivity(status[statusRotate], {
            type: 'PLAYING'
        })
    }

    client.user.setStatus('dnd')

    setInterval(picksStatus, 5000)

    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag} ${client.users.cache.filter(u => !u.bot).size} Member auf ceqoX`);
});
```

Comment: Can’t you use `(await (guild.members.fetch())).size` instead of `client.users.cache.size`?

Comment: `(await guild.members.fetch()).filter(m => !m.user.bot);` this one works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is due to users caching (when a new user joins and the bot doesn't have them cached, it caches them => increases the cache size, but as far as I know, a user leaving all the servers the bot is in doesn't lead to the bot removing it from its cache). Also, your code seems to display all users the bot has cached, so in all servers the bot is in (it might not be a problem if the bot is a personal one for just one server tho).
But assuming you want to display member count of one specific server (that's how it seems to be from reading your question), you could use something like this:

```
client.on('ready', async() => {
  const timer = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
  // Auto Change Status

  async function statusChanging() {
    let guild = await client.guilds.fetch("your_guild_id");
    let members = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter(m => !m.user.bot);
    let membersAmount = members.size;

    let status = [`mit ${membersAmount} User`, `${prefix}help für Hilfe`];

    let statusRotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * status.length);

    client.user.setActivity(status[statusRotate], {
      type: 'PLAYING'
    });
  };

  client.user.setStatus('dnd');

  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag} ${client.users.cache.filter(u => !u.bot).size} Member auf ceqoX`);

  //Someone may have a better way of doing this, but basically this should basically run the function 5 seconds after it finishes (so if it takes 6 seconds to execute, it won't be started in the meantime, but it will be restarted 5 seconds after it finishes executing
  while(true) {
      await statusChanging();
      await timer(5000);
  };
});
```

This should solve the issue.
Also, if you have the server members intent turned on in the developers page, you can use this function:

```
function statusChanging() {
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("845590775450304512");
  const members = guild.members.cache.filter(m => !m.user.bot);
  const membersAmount = members.size;

  let status = [`mit ${membersAmount} User`, `${prefix}help für Hilfe`];

  let statusRotate = Math.floor(Math.random() * status.length);

  client.user.setActivity(status[statusRotate], {
    type: 'PLAYING'
  });
};
```

It scans the cache directly, and the bot should have all the members cached (the intent requires whitelisting after your bot is in 100 servers, but it is fairly easy to get whitelisted + it seems like this is a personal bot, so it shouldn't be an issue). I only suggest it because the function with fetching takes extremely long to execute for me right now, while the cache one is done in few miliseconds.

Comment: This works, but if I leave the code like that, it doesn't give me the Console.log and the status remains online and not on 'DND'. That's why I changed something.
I put the Console.log in the asyn function - `console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag} ${client.users.cache.filter(u => !u.bot).size} Member auf ceqoX`)`
And delete the while loop and change it to the old one.

Comment: Oh yea, I was writing the code at like 11pm so I didn't realise I put the `while(true)` loop before the dnd status setting and the console.log, so of course it would never reach it. Thanks for pointing it out, should be fixed now. @ceqoX